# How to find optimum

Tags: r, loops, minimum, brute-force

I have this dataframe

```
product = data.frame(length = c(100, 200, 300, 400), qty = c(1, 2, 1, 3))
```

And price is defined by this equation `(product[["length"]] * old_const * 2) + setup_price`
where `old_const = 0.0158 and setup_price = 20.8`

```
product[["old_price"]] = (product[["length"]] * old_const * 2) + setup_price
```

And I would like to get rid of constat setup_price by increasing old_const and get new_const which multiply prices and keep my revenues which is:

```
rev1 = sum((product[["length"]] * old_const * 2  + setup_price)* product[["qty"]])
```

So I would like to find `rev1 - rev2 = 0`

```
sum((product[["length"]] * old_const * 2  + setup_price)* product[["qty"]]) - sum((product[["length"]] * old_const * 2)* product[["qty"]]) = 0
```

I generated new const like `const = seq(from = 0.0158, to = 0.018, by = 0.00000001)`

And loop new constant to my equation

```
eval = NULL
diff = NULL

    for(j in 1:length(const)){
        
        eval[j] = sum(((product[["length"]] * const[j] * 2 ))* product[["qty"]])
        diff[j] = rev1 - eval[j]
      }
    plot(const, diff)
```

I can see there is a value of const which get some value close to zero, but I don't know how to get exact value of const?

Any suggestion?
If someone would know more elegant way I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function with the formula in the `for` loop and use `uniroot` to find its root.

```r
product <- data.frame(length = c(100, 200, 300, 400), qty = c(1, 2, 1, 3))

old_const <- 0.0158 
setup_price <- 20.8
rev1 <- sum((product[["length"]] * old_const * 2  + setup_price)* product[["qty"]]) 

fun <- function(x, data, rev1) {
  rev1 - 2 * x * sum(data[["length"]] * data[["qty"]])
}

sol <- uniroot(fun, c(0, 1), product, rev1 = rev1)

ev <- sum(((product[["length"]] * sol$root * 2 ))* product[["qty"]])
rev1 - ev
#> [1] -2.842171e-14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The function evaluated at `sol$root` is zero, give or take floating-point precision.